# Getting an Array from Return statement, deduce a string from that

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, return

I have a 'Case' conditional code snippet wherein I am returning two objects. 
The psuedocode is -

```
case name
when 'a'
object1 = - SQL Logic -
when 'b'
object1 = - SQL Logic -
when 'c'
object2 = - SQL Logic -
when 'd'
object2 = - SQL Logic - 
end
return object1, object2
```

As evident, I am returning two objects. However, in my Controller I need one object at a time. The object are returned in form of Array like ['value', 'nil']. One of them is always nil. 
In my controller I am passing one of these objects as -

```
Model.find_by_sql ["select * from #{object}"]  #either object1 or object2
```

Is there any way that I can break off this array and return the object that is required at that place as String?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return [object1, object2].compact`

you can use `compact` method to remove `nil` value of array.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use `compact` to eliminate the `nil` values from your array, I'm not sure why you need this in the first place.

Doing

```
case name
  when 'a'
    return "SQL statement"
  when 'b'
    return "SQL statement"
  when 'c'
    return "SQL statement"
  when 'd'
    return "SQL statement"
end
```

is way more intuitive.

Comment: Can u also explain to me why if I am trying to access one of the returned object, let's say object1 , it single-handedly behaves as an array. like, object1 - ['value', nil] ?

Comment: It behaves like an array because you return an array. When you return two values, they get put into a single one, an array.

Comment: `case`, not "Case". (Always test!) Consider `case name; when 'a','b','c','d' then return "SQL statement"; end` or `return "SQL statement" if ['a','b','c','d'].include?(name)`. –

Comment: yes thanks for pointing it out..that was actually a Typo..have corrected it now. @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
return (['a', 'b'].include?(name) && - SQL Logic 1 -) ||
         (['c', 'd'].include?(name) && - SQL Logic 2 -)
```

If it's the last line of a method, you don't need `return`.

Let's see what's happening.

If `['a', 'b'].include?(name) #=> true`, `- SQL Logic 1 -`, which is truthy, will be returned.

If `['a', 'b'].include?(name) #=> false`, the first `&&` clause is `false` (`- SQL Logic 1 -` is not executed), so we consider the other `||` clause. `['c', 'd'].include?(name)` must be true, so we return `- SQL Logic 2 -`.